# OCaml Installation, not finding binaries

Tags: installation, ocaml

I am attempting to install and run objective-caml on a remote unix server.

I have successfully built and installed all files included in the ocaml package.  However, when attempting to use it, eg:

```
[~]# ocamllex
```

gives:

```
-bash: /home1/PATHTOMYHOME/local/bin/ocamllex: /usr/local/bin/ocamlrun: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to tell it to look somewhere else for `ocamlrun`?  The correct directory is in the $PATH variable (`ocamlrun` works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the name of the bytecode file to `ocamlrun`:

```
/correct/path/to/ocamlrun /home1/PATHTOMYHOME/local/bin/ocamllex
```

Alternately, it may just work to edit the first line of the bytecode file: there is a #! and a hardcoded path there. The rest of the file is bytecode though, but if your editor does not mess with it, there is a chance...

As a third solution, use the native-compiled version `ocamllex.opt`: it does not rely on `ocamlrun`.

Answer (score 2):

On unix systems, Ocaml bytecode executables begin with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line that gives the path to the bytecode interpreter (`ocamlrun`). It seems that your executables start with `#!/usr/local/bin/ocamlrun`. Change this to `/home1/PATHTOMYHOME/local/bin/ocamlrun`.

If you want `ocamlrun` to be looked up in the `$PATH`, change the shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env ocamlrun`.

Here's a way to change the path to the bytecode executables in the current directories, leaving other files intact. Remove the `*.orig` files once you've checked the replacement works.

```
perl -i.orig -pe 's~^#!.*/ocamlrun.*~#!/usr/bin/env ocamlrun~ if $.==1; close ARGV if eof' *
```

I suggest that you compile OCaml with `./configure -prefix /home1/PATHTOMYHOME/local`. That way all programs will look in the right directories automatically.

Comment: Changing this line to anything results in a `segmetation fault` when trying to run ocamllex.

Comment: @James: That's probably because your editor changed something other than the first line (it probably changed the encoding, or removed some control characters, or something like that). Make sure you use a binary editor, or use the perl command in my revised answer.